# Replacing multiple unique values in a column with 1 ~ 200 in R

Tags: r, loops, object, replace, unique

We have a column filled with unique values (e.g. S09.9, S72.30), in total there are 200 unique values. These values are connected seperately to a few rows (screenshot 1)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA5Av.jpg). We want to replace these values with numbers (1 ~ 200).
Is there a way to do this with a loop or another function. If we want to replace these with the replace functions, that would mean we need to do this by hand and x 200.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, preferably with `dput`..

Comment: You can probably do something like `mydata$ICD10CodeHersen = as.numeric(as.factor(mydata$ICD10CodeHersen))`. But it is unclear exactly what you are trying to do - have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

You could make the code into an ordered or unordered `factor` (See the help with `?factor`). Use `levels` to see the unique values and `count` to count them. And you can create a new numeric code for each unique factor level with `as.numeric`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data
df <- tribble(
  ~code,
  "S09.9",
  "S06.00",
  "S06.00",
  "164",
  "C79.5",
  "S06.00",
  "163.9",
  "S09.9",
  "S06.00",
  "S06.00",
  "R47.0",
  "D43.2",
  "S09.9",
  "S06.00",
  "S09.9",
  "S06.00",
  "G40.3",
  "S09.9"
) |> 
  mutate(code = factor(code))

# Show the unique values (factor levels)
levels(df$code)
#> [1] "163.9"  "164"    "C79.5"  "D43.2"  "G40.3"  "R47.0"  "S06.00" "S09.9"

df |> mutate(code2 = as.numeric(code)) # Replace each level with a number
#> # A tibble: 18 × 2
#>    code   code2
#>    <fct>  <dbl>
#>  1 S09.9      8
#>  2 S06.00     7
#>  3 S06.00     7
#>  4 164        2
#>  5 C79.5      3
#>  6 S06.00     7
#>  7 163.9      1
#>  8 S09.9      8
#>  9 S06.00     7
#> 10 S06.00     7
#> 11 R47.0      6
#> 12 D43.2      4
#> 13 S09.9      8
#> 14 S06.00     7
#> 15 S09.9      8
#> 16 S06.00     7
#> 17 G40.3      5
#> 18 S09.9      8

# Count the occurrences
df |> count(code, sort = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>   code       n
#>   <fct>  <int>
#> 1 S06.00     7
#> 2 S09.9      5
#> 3 163.9      1
#> 4 164        1
#> 5 C79.5      1
#> 6 D43.2      1
#> 7 G40.3      1
#> 8 R47.0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>